# React constructor... not call when component when hidden

Tags: reactjs

Imagine a component, two instances inside a tabs and one outside the tab :

```
<tabs>
  <tab title="1"><MyComponent name="A" /></tab>
  <tab title="2"><MyComponent name="B" /></tab>
</tabs>
<MyComponent name="C" />
```

The first tab is selected by default, A and C constructor as called. The second tab is selected, the constructor of "B" is not called, but it receive props from "A".

So a little question why the full component cycle is not use one B and why A is not unmounted ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a key prop? The example is too short. You should give a larger example.